# ActiveMQ Durable subscribers -- concurrent consumers

Tags: activemq-classic, spring-jms

What is the recommended solution for multiple concurrent consumers for a durable subscribers using sping-jms

Comment: You should upgrade to JMS 2 and use shared subscriptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Virtual Topic instead. Producers send to a specially named topic.. consumers subscribe to a specially named queue (including the ability to have multiple consumers, exclusive consumers, message groups, etc..) Win-win!

http://activemq.apache.org/virtual-destinations.html

Comment: ok, that's very interesting. Let me try with that. qq, will that work for CLIENT_ACK..?

Comment: Yes, it'll work w/ CLIENT_ACK.     BTW-- Per JMS-spec, CLIENT_ACK doesn't do what most ppl think. Be sure you want it to ack all _previous_messages.. if you want real per-message-ack, use INDIVIDUAL_ACK or TRANSACTED

Comment: Thank you Matt-- another favor, i have developed code with ActiveMQ, Sping-JMS. By using DLMC i am configuring listeners, could you please give some spring-jms related virtual topics, subscribers.

Comment: greatly appreciate your help on this.

Comment: i tried googled with Spring-jms with virtual topics, not see much help.

Comment: Nothing special to config on the client-side with Spring-JMS. Once the VirtualTopic config is setup on the broker.. point the producer to a topic and the consumer(s) to queue(s). (Abiding by the special naming convention, of course)

Comment: sweet, let me change & test. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Anytime! Report back success / fail and please accept my answer if it works =)